# Should I get rid of these packages or should I not?

Tags: ubuntu-tweak, software-uninstall

I am pretty new to Ubuntu. Recently, I had some problems with Skype. So I uninstalled/re-installed it. And the problem was solved. I also decided to get rid of the little message/mail indicator on top because I did not want/need it.

I followed the command information I found on the forum. And the indicator went away. So far so good.

Then I pressed apt-get autoremove and got the following:

```
alan@alan-Latitude-D530:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for alan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libcups2:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libgnutls26:i386
  libgpg-error0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libice6:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms1:i386 libmng1:i386 libmysqlclient18:i386
  libp11-kit0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
  libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386
  libqtwebkit4:i386 libsm6:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libtasn1-3:i386
  libthai0:i386 libtiff4:i386 libxi6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxss1:i386
  libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 mysql-common skype-bin:i386 sni-qt:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 48 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 118 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

This was also confirmed at Ubuntu Tweak Janitor, where it says I have 48 unneeded, unnecessary packages that can/should be removed. IT ALSO HAS A SMALL RED CIRCLE BEFORE THIS!! This sure looks like a beware/warning sign to me!!!

My question is: should I get rid of this stuff or did I press a wrong button somewhere, In which case, if I get rid of this stuff will my computer crash and burn! This has happened before!!! Should I worry or is everything ok and I can remove this stuff. To do or not to do: that is the question! If it is really dangerous to eliminate this stuff, then how would I fix Ubuntu Teak Janitor and autoremove at the terminal so I don't get these messages?

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is working as you like, and does not currently 'crash and burn', it should be fine to remove those packages. To quote the manual for apt-get *(`man apt-get`)*:

> **autoremove**
>        autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and
>   are now no longer
>              needed.

The problem with this is that is it *thinks* those packages are no longer needed, as packages with those packages as dependencies are not installed, etc. This is only designed to remove supposedly unneeded packages, with the flaw that they are sometimes wanted *(e.g. `skype-bin`)*. Those packages also only amount to 0.1 Gigabytes, so will not take up loads of space.

If you want to remove some you think you don't need, you can remove them individually with `sudo apt-get remove ...`. Leaving them installed should be fine, it is rare that something just being installed to cause damage.

And if you do decide to remove those packages, hopefully reinstalling them afterwards should resolve any issues - just make a note of what will be removed.